# Is casting a vote to not close a post harder than to close it?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

Is casting a vote to not close a post harder than to close it?

- The options under a post are all various reasons to close a post. Is there no option to not close a post?
- Is the review queue the only place to cast a vote to not close a post? Is there no way to find a post in the review queue, and is it possible that the post may not even appear in the queue for reviewing, which makes it impossible to cast a vote to not close it?

Can casting a vote to not close a specific post be made as easy as to close it?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there no way to find a post in the review queue[?]

This used to be possible from the post timeline, but now the review item only appears in the timeline after it's completed. I think this was done to combat close/reopen wars.

---

> Is the review queue the only place to cast a vote to not close a post?

The current mechanism is that "voting to leave open" only has one effect: if there are a sufficient number of such votes, the post is removed from the close review queue. That's it.

Even if the post is removed from the queue, it can end up closed if a sufficient number do so from the post itself. A vote to leave open does not negate somebody else's vote to close. (I think making it cancel out a vote to close is a declined feature request somewhere on Meta Stack Exchange, but I'm too lazy to look it up now.) As such, the only place where it makes sense to be available is in the review queue.